# Issue with accessing chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, chat

Any reason why accessing **https://chat.stackexchange.com/** is shown as "connection not secure" and unable to connect by the browser ?

Currently on Windows 10 and encountering issue on both browsers: 
Firefox 71.0 (64-bit) and Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[downforeveryoneorjustme](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/chat.stackexchange.com) is saying that chat.stackexchange.com **is up** so not sure if it just me or this issue might be affecting other people.

Did not found any recent post in meta reporting this issue, so thought of posting a question here.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me — Firefox Nightly 73.0a1, Arch Linux.

Comment: [Not re-produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1W27.png) on Windows 10 - Mozilla Firefox 68.0.1 (64-bit) and Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88.

Comment: @Arulkumar I've added browser info to the question, I am on Windows 10 too, but having issue on both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @Shamina I have updated the Firefox to 71.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10, but unable to [re-produce the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD5bn.png). Are you sure, you are disabled all the extensions and user-scripts?

Comment: Is your Anti-virus software interfering with the connection?

Comment: @RobertLongson Dont think so, did not get any anti-virus alert when accessing the site.

Comment: @Arulkumar tried disabling extensions, but still not working. I am able to connect to main stackexchange web site fine, its only chat web site which is not working

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What AV are you using?

Comment: @RobertLongson Antivirus is Windows Security

Comment: Are you on a corporate / school network? A sysdmin might have blacklisted "chat" domains. You can get the details of why firefox thinks it is not secure and find the "view certificate" link to tell you what the certificate is.

Comment: @rene I am on a personal network. Cannot see "view certificate" link in Firefox, in more info section it says "connection not encrypted". Shortly after this question was closed, I was able to access chat website from Chrome for a short time but it does not work anymore on Chrome neither on Firefox. Might be a temporary issue, I will try again later.

Comment: Okay, be advised that some Internet Service Providers play tricks with http traffic. It does sound like something that only affects your setup. A VPN service might be worth trying.

Comment: @rene actually am also connected to a VPN so not sure what is causing the issue.